# Can you use Fencing Grace and Weapon Versatility together?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

[Fencing Grace](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/fencing-grace-combat/) states that you only need to be using a rapier of your size, one-handed, in order to add Dex-to-damage as the only stipulation. Though the name explicitly states "Fencing". Would it go against the rules-as-intended to use [Weapon Versatility](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-versatility-combat/) with it?

Comment: You tagged this rules-as-written, but you're asking about 'RAI' which I assume is 'rules as intended', so I've retagged it for you.  The rules-as-written tag is for questions about what the rules *say*, not what the people writing the rules *meant* to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, you can.

*Fencing Grace* is very specific, it only works with rapiers, and with any other weapons that state that they *work like rapiers*, which don't think that exists yet. But weapon Versatility does not care about the type of the weapon at all, it will simply allow you to change its damage type.

You could say that you are using wide swings when applying slashing damage, or hitting with the guard or pommel for bludgeoning damage, both are valid fencing techniques.

Comment: And nobody will wonder why it does just as much damage as the pointy end. My +1 BAB training of which end to use went right out the door...

Comment: It *only* cost you a feat.